# Import data from google spreadsheet to use with ExtendScript Toolkit

Tags: javascript, csv, google-sheets, extendscript

I'm using adobe's ExtendScript Toolkit to automate some photoshop image creations. I'd like to read a google spreadsheet published (publicly) as a csv, and use data it contains to edit a psd file (where some text layer named "num" is replaced by the content of a column in the spreadsheet). Here's the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16v0CAFL7iBIRGYbQfzmRJNUaI3xytXmkkmloa41BJ5o/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv

And here's my code:

```
#target photoshop

**import google spreadsheet here as a csv, and parse**

for (i = 1; i < num_of_rows_in_csv_file; i++) {

    var fileRef = new File('/file.psd')
    var doc = app.open(fileRef)
    var layer = doc.layers.getByName('num');

    if (layer.kind == LayerKind.TEXT) layer.textItem.contents = content_of_column_A_at_row_i; //replace text by content of cell

    var opts, file;
    opts = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
    opts.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG;
    opts.PNG8 = false;
    opts.quality = 100;

    pngFile = new File("/file_" + i + ".png");
app.activeDocument.exportDocument(pngFile, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, opts);

}
```

How to accomplish this in javascript within ExtendScript?

Comment: What is your question? How to read csv?

Answer (score 2):

## csv reading in extendscript

This scipt asumes that the data.csv is next to the index.js. The content of data.csv is:

```
| num  | name | w    | f    | h    |
| :--: | :--: | :--: | :--: | :--: |
| 1    | A    | 1    | 4    | 2    |
| 2    | B    | 2    | 3    | 1    |
| 3    | C    | 3    | 2    | 4    |
| 4    | D    | 4    | 1    | 3    |
| 5    | E    | 3    | 2    | 2    |
| 6    | F    | 2    | 3    | 1    |
```

This is the quick and dirty approach. For data you don't know how it is formated I suggest using a library like [github.com/Rich-Harris/BabyParse](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/BabyParse). With minor adjustments it works well in ExtendScript.

```
/* global File $ */
/* eslint-disable new-cap */
// tested on osx
var file = File(File($.fileName).parent.fsName + '/data.csv'); // get the file
file.encoding = 'UTF8'; // set some encoding
file.lineFeed = 'Macintosh'; // set the linefeeds
file.open('r',undefined,undefined); // read the file
var content = file.read(); // get the text in it
file.close(); // close it again
var lines = content.split('\n');// split the lines (windows should be '\r')
var data = [];// will hold the data
var keys = lines[0].split(','); // get the heads
// loop the data
for(var i = 1; i < lines.length;i++){
  var obj = {}; // temp object
  var cells = lines[i].split(',');// get the cells
  // assign them to the heads
  obj[keys[0]] = cells[0];
  obj[keys[1]] = cells[1];
  obj[keys[2]] = cells[2];
  obj[keys[3]] = cells[3];
  obj[keys[4]] = cells[4];
  data.push(obj); // add to data
  }

$.writeln(data.toSource()); // show what we got
```

The output is:

```
[({num:"1", name:"A", w:"1", f:"4", h:"2"}), ({num:"2", name:"B", w:"2", f:"3", h:"1"}), ({num:"3", name:"C", w:"3", f:"2", h:"4"}), ({num:"4", name:"D", w:"4", f:"1", h:"3"}), ({num:"5", name:"E", w:"3", f:"2", h:"2"}), ({num:"6", name:"F", w:"2", f:"3", h:"1"})]
```

Comment: thanks! the core of your code works well, but I also need to download (everytime the code is run) the csv from the shared google spreadsheet. Can I simply change the "var file =" to add the url of the csv?

Comment: `File` does not accept an URL you will need to download it in a different way. You could use a CEP panel or a photoshop generator plugin. Or even try to call a system command like curl to download your file.